# База данных Postgresql и Qt

Tags: c++, qt, postgresql, pgadmin4

Мне нужно было написать приложение для учета кадров. Сначала я создал базу данных с помощью pgAdmin. После подключил ее к проекту Qt и стал работать. По окончание мне понадобилось перекинуть приложение на другой компьютер. Как мне сделать, чтобы база данных перемещалась/хранилась вместе проектом?

Каким образом у меня подключена база данных:

```
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setDatabaseName("ModuleCadre");
    db.setUserName("postgres");
    db.setPassword("sadmin");
    if(!db.open()){
        qDebug()<<db.lastError().text();
        return;
    }
    else {
        qDebug()<<"Success";
    }
```

Comment: postgresql не предназначен для распространения вместе с приложением. вам придется делать какой то встроенный инстраллятор постгреса в своем приложении. Если вам нужна БД распространяемая с приложением, смотрите в сторону sqlite

Comment: Если с программой будет работать только один пользователь, используйте embedded СУБД (sqlite/firebird). Либо делайте silent установку pg и создавайте БД скриптом